# Remove a row from an angular $scope promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, ng-grid

Angular is smart enough to directly bind promises.  I have an instance of ng-grid that is bound to a promise returned from a service.  Later I want to remove one record in that grid but am not sure how to do that given I don't have an array to directly manipulate.

For instance the following will throw an error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'splice'" since "gridData" is not actually an array.

```
//Bind promise directly to scope (get returns a promise not an array)
$scope.gridData = myService.get();

//Later I remove a row based on user a user clicking a button on the grid row.
var function = removeRow(rowIdx)
    { 
       $scope.gridData.splice(rowIdx, 1);
    };
```

Ultimately, how can I set scope values to promises and still directly manipulate the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change a promise's value after it has been resolved.

What you can do is set the actual value to a scope property and modify this. In fact, you should get rid of the promise as soon as possible.

```
//Bind promise directly to scope (get returns a promise not an array)
myService.get().then(function (resolved) {
    $scope.gridData = resolved;
});

//Later I remove a row based on user a user clicking a button on the grid row.
function removeRow(rowIdx) { 
   $scope.gridData.splice(rowIdx, 1);
};
```

Comment: Yes. Use promises only for "show only" data... otherwise actually bind the values to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to do this. One of them is to write [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) which slices your array:

```
.filter("slice", function () {
    return function (array, begin, end) {
        if (!angular.isArray(array)) return;
        return array.slice(begin, end);
    };
});
```

And use it on collection inside ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in (data|slice:1)">{{item}}</li>
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6TJFf/1/)

Also, since your data is returned from promise, nothing stops from simply adding [then](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) to controller:

```
$scope.gridData = myService.get().then(function (data) {
    return data.slice(1)
});
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/uXZ2Y/1/)

Comment: I should have been more clear.  Splicing happens at some undetermined point in the future when a user clicks a button in the grid.  This means I populate the grid with the full data set.

Comment: Then instead of slice:1, slice:start should be used with $scope.start === undefined. When user wants to slice the row, you change start value and view gets automatically updated. I've change first example to behave like this, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data array is exposed at `$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.data` (assuming your ngGrid is bound to `gridOptions`) - you may be able to manipulate it directly, though I haven't tried this